# Laravel 5 ; Using count on already filtered data without altering it

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running this code on Laravel. I'm adding filters/ordering if I receive them and I'm altering the query before running it and then paginate the results.

```
$aDatas = DB::table('datas');

if (!empty($aLocations)) {
    foreach ($aLocations as $oLocation) {
        $aDatas->orWhere('pc', '=', $oLocation->pc);
    }
}

if (!empty($oFilters->note)) {
    $aDatas->where('note', '>=', $oFilters->note);
}

if (!empty($oFilters->nb_comments)) {
    $aDatas->where('nb_comments', '>=', $oFilters->nb_comments);
}

if (!empty($oOrder->type)) {
    $aDatas->orderBy($oOrder->type, $oOrder->sort);
}

// echo $aDatas->where('note', '>=', 5)->count() ????
```

It's working fine.
But I'd like to use these results to count several parts of it.
The last line shows what I tried to do, counting how many rows in these filtered results have a note >= 5. But doing this will actually filter my original data.

I thought about assigning $aDatas to another variable and then count on this, but I'll have many counts and that seems dirty.

Is there a sweet way to do this ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Why exactly do you need the counts on each filter?

Comment: I'm showing filters (i.e note filter) with how many results there are of that filter. So if I'm showing only results with more than 3 stars AND more than 50 comments, I'd like to show the user how many of these results have 4 and 5 stars. EDIT : Likely, I'd like to also show how many of these results have 100+ comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just save your datas an replace the last line with this:

```
$datas =$aDatas->where('note', '>=', 5)->get();
echo $datas->count();

//use datas here for more action.
```

Comment: Won't this actually alter the $aDatas result ?

Comment: I thought your aim was it to get all datas to count and to work with it. Then you will need a second variable if you don't want to use more queries.

Comment: I want the datas to use them, and then I want to have multiple count inside these datas.
So the result would be a page where the filtered datas are shown as a whole, and then there are statistics showing how many have this or this filter. But I don't want to change the datas that are shown during this process.

Answer (score 0):

For all of your requirement, you might want to resolve in making several queries because a single query will not be able to do that(based from what I know)

```
//this is to get your total of note greater than 5
$query = DB::table('datas');
$query->where('note', '>=', 5);
$data = $query->paginate(10);

$count = $data->getTotal();
```

to get your other data

If you are working with pagination, use getTotal() instead

```
$query = DB::table('datas');
$query->select(
    DB::raw('COUNT(stars) AS count'),
    DB::raw('starts'),
);
$query->where('notes', '>=', 5);
$query->groupBy('stars');
$data = $query->get();
```